# Set IDs through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have the following code but it cannot be directly edited

```
<div class="slide-content">
<iframe src="sdsdsds" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="Bing"     webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</li>
<li class="slide" data-thumb="sdsdsdsd">
<div class="slide-content">
<iframe src="sdsdsdsd" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="Walmart"     webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
</li>
```

I want to set IDs for the iframes so they become like so

```
 <iframe id="IFRAME1" src="sdsdsds" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="Bing"     webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm somewhat proficient in PHP but don't know how to do this; this would have to be in the code and set through some way.

Help! :-)

Comment: Look into DOMDocument, or one of the many other DOM parsers

Comment: if you cant edit it then you can't add an id element

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `src=` attributes, you can do this with JavaScript.  I know that's not what you asked for, but I believe it'll work.

You can get a collection of `iframe` elements with `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')`.  A collection behaves like an array, so you can iterate over it.  Check the `src=` attribute (available in the `.src` property), figure out the ID you want to use, and use `setAttribute("id", "whatever");` to set an ID on each iframe.  You can hook this to `onload` and the iframes will have IDs when you need them.